# Error al instalar pillow en python

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

C:\Users\Franco>pip install Pillow

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\franco\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\Franco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install Pillow'

Comment: Hola Franco bienvenido al sitio al parecer ya tienes algo de tiempo visitandolo,debes saber que la forma en como preguntastes no es la correcta recuerda que esto no es un servicio tecnico que se paga

Comment: Me ayudaste mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a actualizar el paquete pip

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Y vuelve a intentar instalarlo

Comment: Ya lo intente, y no funciono

Comment: y con: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`?

Comment: Tampoco, me sigue saliendo el mismo error :/

Comment: Si lo reinstalo se arreglara?

Comment: puede ser, pruebalo y me comentas

Comment: Tampoco, no funciono

Comment: Ya lo solucione, borre todo lo que tenia que ver con python y instale una versión antigua, gracias por tu ayuda.